Bounding L1 norm of gaussian convolution
Consider this

Here

I do not agree with the argument. In particular, I  do not see why the second line of the proof, where we seem to be using Cauchy-Swartz, must hold. I know that it is not Cauchy-Swartz as $L^1$ is not an inner product space. Can someone clarify what is going on?

Please share the link or reference to the source, otherwise, it's hard to tell what this is from and what notation/results they might be using.

Hi @ClementC. This is from my notes on a course that I took. There were no official notes but the lecturer sometimes referred to https://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Lectures/pm.pdf. In particular, see page 39.

Thank you for having a look, I think it is probably a mistake from my side. Feel free to post this as an answer.

(deleted my comment -- I'll post this as an answer, after checking it)

Sorry -- what I had written didn't seem as obvious as I thought, or I confused myself, and now I have to run somewhere. But you may want to look at pp. 72-74 of this? https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/II_M/probability_and_measure.pdf

And importantly, there might be a typo in your lecture notes, or the last link I posted -- since what you wrote above (where the RHS features $|\hat{f}|_1$) is not the same as what the link you gave states (Section 7.4), where the RHS has $|f|_1$.

Hi, thank you for this. I will try to investigate this further and ping you if I manage to figure it out.

I realized you want to bound the $L_1$ norm of the Fourier transform of the convolution of two densities, so I deleted my answer. I first thought you want to bound the $L_1$ norm of the convolution of two densities.

What is your question precisely? Is it $|\widehat f\cdot \widehat{g_t}|_1\le |\widehat f|_1 \cdot | \widehat g_t|_1$?

@SangchulLee I think that solves it. Feel free to post this as an answer and I will gladly accept it.

Glad it helped! I moved my comment to an answer. :)

(Migrated from comment.)
The inequality doesn't seem to be true. If we plug $f = g_t$, so that $f\ast g_t=g_{2t}$, then the inequality would imply
$$ \frac{(2\pi)^{d/2}}{(2t)^{d/2}}=\|\widehat{g_t\ast g_t}\|_1 \color{red}{\stackrel{?}{\leq}}\|\widehat{g_t}\|_1\|\widehat{g_t}\|_1=\left(\frac{(2\pi)^{d/2}}{t^{d/2}}\right)^2. $$
This, however, fails to hold for some $t> 0$.

Great! I will award the bounty as soon as it allows me to.

@MathsWizzard Thank you for the award!
